# How to get file size from url in Lua?

Tags: url, lua, filesize

I want to get file's size from a url that it is uploaded into it.

I have a url of a picture.
I want to get it's size using the url in Lua but I don't know how

Thanks.

Comment: What have you try ?

Comment: What do you mean [try]?
I just want a method, function or code to get file size uploaded in url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function get_resource_size(url)
   local pipe = io.popen('wget -S --spider --no-check-certificate "'..url..'" 2>&1')
   local size = pipe:read"*a":match"Content%-Length: (%d+)"
   pipe:close()
   return size and tonumber(size)
end

print(get_resource_size(
   "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/282ad8d2c96e9b753bde22ac6ca0918b?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG"
))
```

Your avatar has size of 2074 bytes